Copy the content button in a custom copilot created using Copilot Studio
I have a created a Custom Copilot created using Copilot Studio(low code/no code) deployed to Microsoft Teams and would like to add the "Copy" button so that all the contents generated in the response (it can be anything either text response or adaptive card) can be copied to clipboard by a button click like the functionality which is already available in all the GenAI capable bots like ChatGPT / Copilot for M365.
Or even I can go for classical method of Navigator copy to clipboard function but I am not sure how to add Javascript function to the adaptive card / text responses generated.
Any pointers or idea would greatly help me.
TIA

Copy function is available for MS teams tab or teams message extension but here we are rolling out as MS Teams chat app so adaptive card is not supporting the copy function unless we write a code to deploy the function.

We shared this feedback here https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/3e493e1c-b284-ef11-9442-002248546a2e.
